# How do I redirect this url pattern in asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-6, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect a user when they entire a URL in this format:

```
http://example.com/http://example2.com/
```

To the following:

```
http://example.com/?m=example2.com#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example2.com%2F
```

I want to strip out the host of example2 and make it a query-string, then URL encode the full URL of example2 and put it as the anchor.

What is the best way to do this in asp.net? I can use mvc, iis7, or iis6. I know I could do this by mapping everything to .NET in IIS6 and then using httpcontext.rewritepath but I bet there is a better way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ASP.NET does not allow a colon anywhere in the URL path.  Not even an escaped colon (%3A).  It is only allowed in the querystring portion of the path.

This restriction is in place even before URL rewriting happens.  (You'll get the [400 Bad Request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948428/asp-net-http-400-bad-request-error-when-trying-to-process-http-localhost5957).)  In that question, the asker answered their own question with a link to [Stefan from the ASP.NET team](http://forums.asp.net/p/1431148/3221542.aspx).

Of course, you can still collect the URL from your user any way you like, and format the URL or redirect in a way that ASP.NET can use.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about urlrewritting concept of ASP.net. I think it can solve your purpose

Comment: when my friends told me about stackoverflow i had no idea it would be this useful : )

Comment: even when i started i was also not having any idea that it will be useful any ways i am happy that you get an idea for what you are looking